# SQL relational tables, linking tables

Tags: sql

So I'm not sure if I'm using the right term for this, or if there's already guides on this (I'm not sure how to call it so I can't find much info on it)

So, I've got 3 tables

1. A user table
2. A Google user table
3. A Facebook user table.

My question is, Is it better to put a `link-ID` to the `Google table+Facebook table` or is it better to make two more tables that link the others together.

Ex. 
**USER TABLE**

```
User ID
Google ID
Facebook ID
```

Or 2 tables that link to the main tables

**GOOGLE LINK TABLE**

```
User ID
Google ID
```

**FACEBOOK LINK TABLE**

```
User ID
Facebook ID
```

Comment: Its better to use one table and add one column `RegisterType="Google|Facebook|Linkedin"`

Comment: what is your requirements as a whole?

Comment: i am against @Justcode since in this way you will lose the integrity, better to use another 2 tables ( applying normalization rule) and then you can create a view with additional column ( registertype) if you want

Comment: @Just code what happens if a user registers with their Facebook then change their registered email then try sign in again through Facebook. How would I keep the two linked?

Comment: @muhammad muazzam requirements? Table wise? I'd just like to store general info like the ID and email+name associated with the account. Don't think I'll need email+name though

Comment: You don't need to worry about that. You need to update existing record to `RegisterType="Facebook"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, better to use the following

```
Users (UserId,UserName,PasswordHash--,...other fields)
GoogleUsers (UserId,GoogleId--,...other fields)
FacebookUsers(UserId,FacebookId--,...other fields)

create view (UserId,InternalKey,UserType--,...other fields)
as
   select UserId,FacebookId,'Facebook'--,...other fields
   from FacebookUsers
   union all
   select UserId,GoogleId,'Google'--,...other fields
   from GoogleUsers
   union all
   select UserId,UserId,'Local Users'--,other fields
   from Users u
   where not exists(select 1 from FacebookUsers f where f.UserId=u.UserId)
   and not exists(select 1 from GoogleUsers g where g.UserId=u.UserId)
```